# How can I download lubuntus manual?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu

https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/# hoping to download this for offline reading but I'm unaware of how I could accomplish.

Comment: Scroll down a bit, there is a "Contact us" section. :~)

Comment: Read `man wget`, especially the section "`Recursive Retrieval Options`".

Comment: I can't/ won't read the unformatted text in your comment.  Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Don't use Add Comment, or you'll classify yourself as "Does Not Follow Instructions (DNFI)", and I'll ignore you. I view DNFIs as unhelpable.

Comment: Maybe asking at https://discourse.lubuntu.me will be more successful.

Comment: @sudodus may have already asked; we've had a task about it for awhile, but lacking time/resources we've been unable to achieve it..  https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/offline-version-of-the-lubuntu-manual/4313 and https://phab.lubuntu.me/T109   (FYI:  *I recall discussions on it, but my knowledge on that task is very outdated sorry*)

Comment: @guiverc ok I see thank you guiverc. :)

Comment: @DudlyDog, There is a working recipe to create an off-line Lubuntu manual at [Lubuntu Discourse](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/offline-version-of-the-lubuntu-manual/4313) now.

Comment: @suddodus Very interesting I assumed it would be much easier to turn a website like this into a pdf had no clue,  currently watching a video about Practical Sphinx right now and have the manual downloaded thanks guys!

Comment: I'll provide a link to where you can read the 22.10 manual here - https://people.ubuntu.com/~nio-wiklund/LubuntuManual_version-22.10_2023-06-17.pdf   It was created & uploaded by @sudodus so all thanks should go to him!  *Nio (sudodus) will write an answer when he can; we don't currently have a 23.04 manual available yet, but 22.10 is pretty close*  ... (Also my prior T109 link wasn't helpful; I'd mixed up tasks sorry.. see https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/offline-version-of-the-lubuntu-manual/4313/ )

Comment: FYI:  You don't mention what release you're using, but your manual URL shows *stable* which is current Lubuntu 23.04 (ie. very close to 22.10).  If you're using Lubuntu 22.04 LTS or the *lts* release (*with its much older LXQt I think you've mentioned in other question(s)*) the appropriate URL in your question would have been https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/#  (ie. STABLE in the URL will be LTS)  https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/manual-links-currently-available-22-04-lts-23-04-stable/3242

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that the original poster @DudlyDog has already solved the problem, but I think this answer can be useful for other users of Lubuntu.

### Alternative 1 - make your own manual

At [Lubuntu Discourse](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/offline-version-of-the-lubuntu-manual/4313/5) I was told how to create a pdf manual,

```
mkdir lubuntu
cd lubuntu
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends python3-pip python3-sphinx latexmk texlive texlive-formats-extra build-essential python3-sphinx-rtd-theme python3-sphinx-bootstrap-theme
git clone 'https://phab.lubuntu.me/source/manual.git' # not sure if this is the current git repository
cd manual
make latexpdf
```

The created pdf can be found in the “build/latex” directory.

This should give you the newest possible version.

### Alternative 2 - download an uploaded version of the manual

Download [LubuntuManual_version-22.10_2023-06-17.pdf](https://people.ubuntu.com/%7Enio-wiklund/LubuntuManual_version-22.10_2023-06-17.pdf)

This is an easy way to get a working version, but it might not be quite up to date.